# How to clear TextField in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi everyone i have a question regarding on how to clear TextField after clicking the icon? thanks

```
const [filteredLocations, setFilteredLocations] = useState(locations);

const clearSearch = () => {
    // i dont know what should i put here TextField.clear() or so what ever
  };
  const filterResults = (e) => {
    ....
    setFilteredLocations(filteredLocations);
  };

    <TextField
      placeholder="Search Locations"
      onChange={filterResults}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton onClick={clearSearch} edge="end">
            <ClearIcon />
          </IconButton>
        )
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Your `TextField` is not controlled, so there is no way to change its value. See [uncontrolled vs controlled](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the whole solve. There was an error in the `filterResults` function.

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ClearOutlined'

export default function App() {
  const [filteredLocations, setFilteredLocations] = useState('');

const clearSearch = () => {
    setFilteredLocations('')
  };
  const filterResults = (e) => {
    setFilteredLocations(e.target.value);
  };

    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
      placeholder="Search Locations"
      value={filteredLocations}
      onChange={filterResults}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton onClick={clearSearch} edge="end">
            <ClearIcon />
          </IconButton>
        )
      }}
    />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesnadbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-clear-textfield-in-react-tb73t

Comment: it doesnt work @moshfiqrony, when i click the textField i got an error `The above error occurred in the <e> component:`

Comment: There was an error in your filterResults funtion. Check the solve again. I also added working codesnadbox link

Comment: cant type in your Codesnadbox

Comment: Are you sure? Because I am able to write there. In incognito as well

Answer (score 2):

```
const [filteredLocations, setFilteredLocations] = useState(locations);

const clearSearch = () => {
  setFilteredLocations("");
  };
  const filterResults = (e) => {
    ....
    setFilteredLocations(filteredLocations);
  };

    <TextField
      value = {filteredLocations}
      placeholder="Search Locations"
      onChange={filterResults}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton onClick={clearSearch} edge="end">
            <ClearIcon />
          </IconButton>
        )
      }}
    />
```

User a state to keep the text. And use that value as textare value. Change that state to empty inside clearSearch function.

Comment: it doesnt work @Kasun, when i click the textField i got an error `The above error occurred in the <e> component:`